# Spring Security login with a rest web service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-webflow

I have a SpringMVC web application that needs to authenticate to a RESTful web service using Spring Security.And i need to access this same application through a rest client.

Here is What I need to implement

**The accept header is application/json(For a java rest client )**

- After a successful login, It will be sent a token(Or sessionId) to rest client in the format of json
- After a login failure,It will be sent error message in the format of json.

**For a web request**

- After a successful login,It will be redirecting to a success jsp page.
- After a login failure,It will be sent error message to the same loin page.

How can i do this with spring mvc and spring security?.I have very less time to do this,any one please give me an example with spring-security.xml.

Thanks

Comment: Rethink your logic immediately. This is not how REST works. REST is stateless, you need header-based auth like Basic, Digest, Negotiate. The client or even browser will do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

my recommendation is as below. you can use standard web security to call RESTFul service, first authenticate with user and password and get cookies, if using java based server, send this as cookie to server on subsequent rest calls. I have written is Spring Java code which can get session cookies for you. 
There is no need for separate json service to get token.

```
public class RestAuthClient {
    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8888/ecom";
    public String authenticateGetCookie(String user, String password){
        HttpMessageConverter<MultiValueMap<String, ?>> formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();

        HttpMessageConverter<String> stringHttpMessageConverternew = new StringHttpMessageConverter();

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new LinkedList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();

        messageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        messageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverternew);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("j_username", user);
        map.add("j_password", password);

        String authURL = baseUrl+"/j_spring_security_check";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map,
                requestHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(authURL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        HttpHeaders respHeaders = result.getHeaders();      
        System.out.println(respHeaders.toString());

        System.out.println(result.getStatusCode());

        String cookies = respHeaders.getFirst("Set-Cookie");
        return cookies;
    }
    public void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing your custom *AuthenticationSuccessHandler* and *AuthenticationFailureHandler* as described below.

You might also need to implement some simple controllers which you will be redirecting to from AuthenticationHandlers. There's a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205436/spring-mvc-spring-security-login-with-a-rest-web-service) of how to implement REST auth in Spring. So I beleive combining these two answers will give you a solution.

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // get accept headers from request
        // Redirect successfully logged in user to another url depending on the accept headers) 
        // put session id in response if needed
        ((WebAuthenticationDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()).getSessionId();            
        String targetUrl = ""; //TODO insert here
        response.sendRedirect(targetUrl);
    }
}

public class AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // get accept headers from request
        // set failure url      
        // Do redirecting job
        setDefaultFailureUrl(FAILURE_URL);
        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }   
}
```

In your security.xml

```
<http entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/views/errors/error403.jsp" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        ...
    <custom-filter ref="loginFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        ...
</http>

<!-- Login filter and entry point -->   
<beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/signin" /></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="loginFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager"        ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl"           value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authFailureHandler"/></beans:bean>
    <!-- Login filter and entry point -->          
    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.example.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>    
    <beans:bean id="authFailureHandler" class="com.example.security.AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl"/>            
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: This is deemed to fail. A REST client is stateless and has no idea about form auth. Only header-based auth will work.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you bring up a really good point. I've updated the answer, however it would be good to test it anyway.